# getCurrentAttribute link to parent item? Netsuite

Tags: html, scripting, netsuite

I have this piece of code here. works great. It's a child item of a parent item. Just displaying the name of the Child Item.

```
<span class="item-list-cell-name"> <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','displayname')%></span>
```

I want to link this back to the parent item.but I'm having a problem with the link.

```
<A href="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','storeurl')%>"></A>
```

the <%=getCurrentAttribute seems to be custom language that NetSuite has created. I'm not sure how this should look if I want it to link back to the parent ('item', 'storeurl')

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Note that getCurrentAttribute is explained in the NS help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a sub item and you want its parent item drilldown page? If so you are out of luck as far as a general answer. If you are trying to just get back to the parent category you can use:

```
<a href="<%=getCurrentAttribute('sitecategory','canonicalurl')%>">Up</a>
```

If it's the parent item link you want then what you can do is create custom hyperlink field on the item record and populate it with a script.

Comment: It's a child sub item and I want to link to the parent drilldown page. seems so simple too. Bummer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the easiest and best solution to link a child item to it's Parent Item in netsuite would be.

1. Create a custom field on the parent Item.
2. copy the urlcomponent to that custom field.

then you can just pull it back in like this here,

```
<A href="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','customfield')%>"><span class="item-list-cell-name"> <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','displayname')%></span></A>
```